# Jenkins Workflow and Script Security Plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

When writing Groovy workflow code that is loaded via SCM and uses third party classes and methods, is it possible to **avoid** the **sandbox** and have my methods executed by default, *without* being rejected with security exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

Create the workflow item as an administrator (a user with Overall/RunScripts permission)